# Multi param values are not replaced properly in the path

Tags: karate

[image]I have multiple parameters in the REST call as shown below

/integration/live/rest/accessProfile?page=0&pageSize=10&sortBy=name&fieldList=name,id,date_created,date_modified,created_id,modified_id&filter=id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27200%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27100%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27101%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27102%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27103%27%20&getTotalRecordCo

My code is
* params { page: '0', pageSize: '10',sortBy: 'name', fieldList: ['name','id', 'date_created', 'date_modified', 'created_id', 'modified_id'],filter: 'id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27200%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27100%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27101%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27102%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27103%27%20',getTotalRecordCount:true }

And path '/integration/live/rest/accessProfile'

When I am running the test cases the path is not properly replaced in the REST call

After running the actual call sent to the server is

https://vm-trunk-wmic-01.eur.ad.sag/integration/live/rest/accessProfile?page=0&pageSize=10&sortBy=name&fieldList=name&fieldList=id&fieldList=date_created&fieldList=date_modified&fieldList=created_id&fieldList=modified_id&filter=id%2520not%2520equal%2520to%2520%2527200%2527%2520AND%2520id%2520not%2520equal%2520to%2520%2527100%2527%2520AND%2520id%2520not%2520equal%2520to%2520%2527101%2527%2520AND%2520id%2520not%2520equal%2520to%2520%2527102%2527%2520AND%2520id%2520not%2520equal%2520to%2520%2527103%2527%2520&getTotalRecordCount=true

All the params are replaced properly except for 'fieldList' parameter in the path.

I am looking for correct syntax to pass my below REST call

/integration/live/rest/accessProfile?page=0&pageSize=10&sortBy=name&fieldList=name,id,date_created,date_modified,created_id,modified_id&filter=id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27200%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27100%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27101%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27102%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27103%27%20&getTotalRecordCount=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`* params { fieldList: 'name,id,date_created,date_modified,created_id,modified_id' }`

EDIT: please note that commas will be URL-encoded as per the HTML spec. If you really want to "see" the commas, build the `url` yourself.

For an example of the 2 ways to do this, see this commit: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/14c6321606bb6bcb626614248f85cc8ea50c61b6

Comment: Hi Peter,  Thank you for the response. But Still the solution suggested is not working. comma(,) is replaced with %2Cid%2C in the REST call. The replaced REST call with suggested syntax is fieldList=name%2Cid%2Cdate_created%2Cdate_modified%2Ccreated_id%2Cmodified_id.

Comment: @Anupama actually this is the correct behavior: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp - and your server should be able to decode the param correctly. if the server cannot debug this - it is a bug on the server-side. if you really insist on seeing comma in the URL, you have a workaround - use the URL, see my edit

Comment: Hi Peter, As you said it's a bug with server side. As you suggested the workaround - 'params in url' is working perfectly fine. Thank you :) Working code is Given url appServer +'/integration/live/rest/accessProfile'+'?page=0'+'&pageSize=10'+'&sortBy=name'+'&fieldList=name,id,date_created,date_modified,created_id,modified_id'+'&filter=id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27200%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27100%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27101%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27102%27%20AND%20id%20not%20equal%20to%20%27103%27%20'+'&getTotalRecordCount=true' 003ms